# Self invoking anonymous function vs Object oriented approach to prevent effecting global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning Jquery and in my learning process I learned how to not pollute global namespace.
I've learned two approaches:

1. Using self invoking anonymous function [( IIFE )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).
2. Using Object oriented approach in which we create an object which will hold our variables and object will be used to access that variable without affecting Global namespace.

Now my question is,which one is more professional and a better way to prevent polluting global namespace.I think using self closing anonymous function is better as it don't add even a single name.But in Object Oriented approach only objects name is added to global namespace.
**The answer suggests both are same but everything has pros and cons so which on should I use preferably.**

Comment: _self closing anonymous function_ Maybe you mean [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)?

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions to combine both practices. You can build applications in the way like this:

```
(function () {

    function Greeter(text) {

        this.greetPhrase = text;

    }

    Greeter.prototype = {

        greet : function () {

            alert(this.greetPhrase);

        }

    };

    var greeterInstance = new Greeter('Hello');

    greeterInstance.greet();

})();
```